# Selector Href not identified

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, href

I have this code that goes to a YouTube link of a keyword, finds videos uploaded less than 5 minutes ago, and comments on them.

However the problem is that the loop to check for the selector's href of "uploaded x *mins/secs* ago" does not work, and when there are videos with those upload times, it just refreshes the page.

I haven't tried anything as nothing I can think of works. I'd love some assistance, it's really annoying me.
**I don't know how to make minimal code for here if it recreates the problem without being the full code.**

this is the problem:

```
// collecting links
  let linked = [];
  while (linked.length === 0) {
    linked = await Promise.all((await page.$$(selector.videoTitleinSearch)).map(async a => {
      const uploadedago = await a.$(selector.uploadedago);
      if (uploadedago) {
        const href = await uploadedago.getProperty('href').jsonValue();
        if (href &&
          (href.includes("5 minutes ago") ||
            href.includes("4 minutes ago") ||
            href.includes("3 minutes ago") ||
            href.includes("2 minutes ago") ||
            href.includes("1 minute ago") ||
            href.includes(" seconds ago") ||
            href.includes(" second ago"))
        ) {
          return {
            url: await a.getProperty('href').jsonValue(),
            title: await a.getProperty('title').jsonValue()
          };
        }
      }
      return null; // add this line to return null if uploadedago is not found
    }));
    linked = linked.filter(Boolean); // add this line to remove null values from linked array
    if (linked.length === 0) {
      console.log("No videos found, refreshing page...");
      await page.reload({
        waitUntil: "networkidle2"
      });
      await page.waitForTimeout(5000);
    }
```

Below is all of the code for anyone who wants the full thing (main.js).

https://mega.nz/folder/VENDwBIQ#upEg3eQo496hVwVx6WPtTg

Disclaimer: I am only using this for my own channels, I'm just using other videos to verify things are working before putting my effort of uploading videos, just to find out something doesn't work; so this is just easier to test.

Comment: Apparently you're using some kind of framework for this? Puppeteer? Playwright? Selenium? Something else? Please [edit] your question with the tag of the framework. Rather than simply giving people the entirety of the code and asking for them to debug the whole thing, it is preferred that you narrow it down to a [mre]. See [ask] for more tips.

Comment: `for (i in link) {` creates a global and `in` isn't a good way to iterate over arrays. Use `for (const link_ of link) {` although ideally you'd name this such that the `link` array is plural, `for (const link of links)`. Beyond that, there's a lot of code here. Can you create a runnable [mcve] that directly goes right to whatever the issue is and includes an actual sample channel?

Comment: Context is good, but there's a lot of noise like spinners and missing `config` object though that prevents me from copying and running this. If there's a good deal of effort I have to put in just to run the project, I usually skip answering. After your edit, now I really can't run the code. I suggest setting up the post like this: [goal/desired outcome] [problem statement/issue you're encountering, with no distractions or unnecessary code] [copy-pastable code that runs to show the problem/issue occurring] [specific technical question you're asking about the problem/issue]. Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen so you want my all code?

Comment: No, as mentioned I want a [mcve]. Please read the link if you're not sure what that means. It says "
    Minimal: Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem.
    Complete: Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem in the question itself.
    Reproducible: Test the code you're about to provide to make sure it reproduces the problem
". Your first post wasn't minimal or complete (runnable with a copy-paste). After the edit, it was more minimal but less complete. We need the bare minimum, runnable code to reproduce the problem, no distractions.

Comment: @ggorlen I have no ideas how to make that. I also don't understand the meanings because of the website's in english not my language. (idk how to change the language if that's actually a thing

Comment: Fair enough, but you're less likely to get an answer without doing a bit more work to strip out the code that isn't part of the problem. You're essentially asking other people to do that work for you, and most won't bother, speaking as the most active Puppeteer answerer in this tag at the present.

Comment: My meaning is that if it needs configuration like a comment, and keyword for it to work, as well as cookies, how am I meant to change that to get the code to work if you're not logged into the browser? most of the code is there which won't change much other than removing like 10 lines. It does the same thing no matter what.